# Welche Aussprache des Buchstaben j ist häufiger/üblicher - [ʝ] oder [j]?

Tags: pronunciation

Zum Beispiel werden in [diesem Hörbeispiel auf dict.cc vom Wort "jemand"](https://www.dict.cc/?s=jemand) (du musst auf den kleinen Lautsprecher klicken) 4 von den 5 menschlichen Beispielen mit [ʝ] ausgesprochen (die einzige Ausnahme ist Taixum24, der stellt eigentlich beide Aussprachen bereit). Beide computergenerierten Beispiele werden allerdings mit [j] ausgesprochen. Beim Wort ["jemals"](https://www.dict.cc/?s=jemals) bekommt man jeweils 2 davon.

[Referenz](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liste_der_IPA-Zeichen) für die, die nicht wissen, wovon ich rede.

Comment: Ich habe mir alle Beispiele angehört und höre nur [j], etwas anderes hätte mich auch stark verwundert.

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich, wenn ich die Beispiele von Halmafelix anhöre (sowohl "jemand" als auch "jemals"), ist das ʝ so stark (für mich - vielleicht bin ich verrückt), dass es sich fast wie das französiches j [ʒ] anhört.

Comment: Hm, also ich höre da ein leichtes Ausatmen, das vielleicht.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ich kann gut nachvollziehen was du da hörst. Die Antwort lautet, wie so oft: Es gibt regionale Unterschiede.

Besonders bei der Aussprache des Wortes durch den Sprecher Halmafelix, der laut [Benutzerinformation](https://users.dict.cc/Halmafelix/?ref=ah786983&_gl=1*15fwu5x*_ga*NTkyNTI0Mzk2LjE3MDg1MDcxMTg.*_ga_QGHHZZFXXG*MTcwODUwNzExNy4xLjEuMTcwODUwNzMxNi42MC4wLjA.) aus Hamburg ist, ist ziemlich klar der Laut [ʝ] am Beginn des Wortes zu hören. Laut Selbstbeschreibung ist er *»Professioneller Sprecher, Rezitator, Diplom-Sprecherzieher«* und fühlt sich berufen, auf dict.cc Aussprachevarianten zu hinterlassen, wenn es seiner Meinung nach solche Varianten gibt. Ich würde seine Aussprachebeispiele daher im Zweifel nicht als die Standard-Aussprache ansehen, sondern als eine Variante, die ihm in Hamburg und Umgebung schon mal untergekommen ist.

Der Sprecher [Taixum24](https://users.dict.cc/Taixum24/?ref=ah1472158&_gl=1*3mej8l*_ga*NTkyNTI0Mzk2LjE3MDg1MDcxMTg.*_ga_QGHHZZFXXG*MTcwODUwNzExNy4xLjEuMTcwODUwNzc3OC42MC4wLjA.), der beide Varianten hinterlassen hat, lebt südlich von Berlin, gibt aber sonst nicht viel von sich bekannt.

[Immanuel](https://users.dict.cc/Immanuel/?ref=ah219214&_gl=1*1k0l773*_ga*NTkyNTI0Mzk2LjE3MDg1MDcxMTg.*_ga_QGHHZZFXXG*MTcwODUwNzExNy4xLjEuMTcwODUwNzg4Ny42MC4wLjA) ist Berliner und spricht fließend Sächsischen und Berlinerischen Dialekt.

[Connum](https://users.dict.cc/Connum/?ref=ah192704&_gl=1*1sw6hn7*_ga*NTkyNTI0Mzk2LjE3MDg1MDcxMTg.*_ga_QGHHZZFXXG*MTcwODUwNzExNy4xLjEuMTcwODUwODA0Mi40Ny4wLjA.) stammt aus Baden im Südwesten Deutschlands, bei ihm höre ich einen Laut, der zwischen [j] und [ʝ] liegt, aber deutlich näher bei [j] als bei [ʝ].

Ich habe mein ganzes Leben im Osten Österreichs verbracht (in den Bundesländern Steiermark, Wien und Niederösterreich), und kann berichten, dass in dieser Region der Laut [ʝ] völlig ungebräuchlich ist. Ich schaffe es nicht einmal, das Wort *»jemand«* so auszusprechen, dass ein [ʝ] zu hören ist.

Ich scheitere aber auch, wie fast alle Österreicher, regelmäßig bei dem Versuch, ein stimmhaftes S ([z]) auszusprechen. In Österreich ist jedes S stimmlos ([s]), und ich sehe da durchaus einen Zusammenhang, denn der Wechsel von [j] zu [ʝ] erfordert eine Bewegung im Sprechapparat, die sehr ähnlich zu jener ist, die man vollführen muss, um aus einem [s] ein [z] zu machen. Diese Bewegung wird im Süden des deutschen Sprachraums nicht gemacht, daher werden dort die Laute [z] und [ʝ] nicht verwendet.

Daher kann man sagen, dass in Österreich (und vermutlich auch in der Schweiz, das ist aber geraten) ausschließlich die Aussprache mit [j] verwendet wird. Ich vermute, dass das auch in Bayern (zumindest in Altbayern) so der Fall ist. Offensichtlich ist im Norden und Nordosten Deutschlands aber die Variante mit [ʝ] so stark verbreitet, dass von 4 Aussprachebeispiele, die 3 Sprecher aus diesem Gebiet produziert haben, immerhin 3 diese Variante verwenden. Eine dermaßen kleine Stichprobe ist statistisch aber nur sehr wenig aussagekräftig.

---

Zum Sprecher *Halmafelix* ist möglicherweise noch zu ergänzen, dass er, als professioneller Sprecher, ziemlich sicher die [Siebsche Bühnensprache](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deutsche_Aussprache_(Siebs)) erlernt hat. Ein besonders hervorstechendes Merkmal dieser Aussprache ist die besondere Prägnanz der stimmhaften Konsonaten. Das stimmhafte S wird in der Bühnensprache nach Siebs noch stimmhafter ausgesprochen als von Alltagssprechern. Und ich vermute, dass sich das auch auf das erhöhte Ausmaß der Stimmhaftigkeit auswirkt, die beim [ʝ] des Sprechers Halmafelix zu hören ist. Ich halte seine Aussprache daher zwar für sehr deutlich und gut verständlich, aber auch für untypisch.

Comment: Ich bezweifle, dass das [ʝ] wirklich Absicht ist, sondern eher ein Artefakt der gezielten Aufnahme eines einzelnen Wortes. Die "jemand anders"-Beispiele klingen da schon natürlicher. Ich kann Björn Friedrich nur zustimmen, dass [j] die gängige und "normale" Aussprache ist.

Comment: Danke schön, Hubert.